# Selected Non_Aggregate Values must be part of the associated group

Tags: sql, teradata

I get the error message 'Selected Non_Aggregate Values must be part of the associated group' when running the script below. I only have 2 non-aggregated columns that are specified in the group by function.

Am I missing something?

Running code in Teradata.

```
UPDATE SANDBOX_NETWORKUK.MVNO_USAGE     
FROM (
SELECT
REGISTRATION_ID
,ZONE
,SUM(ZEROIFNULL(DURATION_IN_MINS)) AS DURATION_IN_MINS
FROM CALL_DETAILS
WHERE ZONE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY REGISTRATION_ID ORDER BY DURATION_IN_MINS DESC) = 1 )PP
SET 
MOST_USED_ZONE = PP.ZONE
WHERE   SANDBOX_NETWORKUK.MVNO_USAGE.registration_id = PP.registration_id ;
```

Comment: Possibly it is the `QUALIFY` line which uses your aggregate.

Comment: You have used a column name for the name of your sum; the parser thinks DURATION_IN_MINS in the ORDER BY clause refers to the column. Rename the sum to SUM_DURATION_IN_MINS.

Comment: Moreover `ZONE` is an internal keyword in Teradata, enclose it in double quote. If you run `SELECT ZONE` it returns null. I tried running `SELECT
REGISTRATION_ID
,ZONE
,SUM(ZEROIFNULL(DURATION_IN_MINS)) AS SUM_DURATION_IN_MINS
FROM CALL_DETAILS
WHERE ZONE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 1,2
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY REGISTRATION_ID ORDER BY SUM_DURATION_IN_MINS DESC) = 1 ` , it returned 0 rows because of the condition `WHERE ZONE is not null` condition.